# Check if text is selected on keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a scenario where i prevent user from entering 2nd numeric after a decimal.I have my code on keydown event.
Below is my code:

```
$scope.Inputkeydown = function (event, value) {        
    if (event.keyCode != 8) {
        if (value != null && value != undefined && value != "") {
            var regex = /^\d*\.\d$/;  //this regex passes only decimal numbers with one digit after decimal
            if (regex.test(value)) {                   
                    event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }

};
```

Now the trouble is if user selects on the text(say 50.0) in the textbox and say presses 5 at that time it is getting prevented too, as in the textbox value is 50.0 and regex allows it go and it is getting prevented from being typed in.

Can i check on keydown if text is being copied?? or is there any other way around?

Comment: Have you tried to trigger this on `KeyPress` ?

Comment: You want the user to let enter digit if value after decimal is zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of preventing the user from entering it, you could just remove it after keypress:

```
function filterDecimals(inp) {
    return inp.replace(/^(\d*\.\d)\d*$/g, '$1');
}
```

Or, if you want to remove everything after it, replace the second `\d*` with `.*`

**EDIT (example of usage)**

This function takes the text as input and returns the new filtered text. To use this, just attach an event handler on `keypress` like so:

```
<input type="text" id="filteredbox">

<script>
var txt = document.getElementById("filteredbox");

// on keyup event (you can change to keypress if you want, but this is more logical here
txt.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
    // sets value of txt to the returned data from filterDecimals()
    // if statement: only filters it if necessary; this eliminates the "selected text" issue you mentioned
    if (this.value !== filterDecimals(this.value)) {
        this.value = filterDecimals(this.value);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: any way i can do it on keydown ??

Comment: I'm not sure what your code looks like, but I've edited my answer with an example. Please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Woops! Edited my code again to fix an error. This should work for you now.